# React Router Conflicts two routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Below is my attached routes, When I navigate to /login/schoolname. I get the correct component, but when I navigate to  the verify, it appends onto /login/verify.

```
<Switch> 
  <Route path="/verify" component={Verify} />
  <Route path="/login/:schoolName" component={Login} />
  <Route path="*" component={Home} />
</Switch>
```

I was expecting, some thing like
    localhost/verify
    localhost/login/schoolname
whenever I click on the navigation

Comment: try exact parametr in route

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change the route in order to match the path exactly

```
<Route exact path="/verify" component={Verify} />
```

and when you manually change the route be sure to put the slash in the front of the route name

```
history.push("/verify");
```